# Can an even square exceed a cube by one?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can an even square exceed a cube by one?

I can't find any examples so I assume it is false. How would I prove it?

I forgot to add that they must be positive.

Comment: Well, there is $(-1)^3+1=0^2$. (There are no others.)

Comment: @JackAidley 1 is not even

Answer (score 9):

Here is a proof using elementary methods:

We want to find positive integer solutions to the equation $(2m)^2 = n^3 + 1$. This is equivalent to $$ n^3 = (2m+1)(2m-1).$$
If $p$ is any prime in the prime factorization of $2m+1$ then from the equation above $p$ divides $n^3$. Because $n^3$ is a perfect cube, the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n^3$ must be divisible by 3. Then since $2m+1$ and $2m-1$ are relatively prime, $2m+1$ must contain all of $n^3$'s factors of $p$. So the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $2m+1$ must be divisible by 3. This is true for *every* prime factor $p$ of $2m+1$, so $2m+1$ is a perfect cube.

Using a similar argument we see that $2m-1$ must also be a perfect cube.

So we have two perfect cubes whose difference is $(2m+1)-(2m-1) = 2$. But this is impossible, since the difference between two (distinct) positive perfect cubes is at least $2^3 -  1^3 = 7$.

Hence the equation $(2m)^2 = n^3 + 1$ has no positive integer solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+1$ only has $(0,\pm 1)$, $(-1, 0)$ and $(2, \pm 3)$ as rational points (not including infinity). The only solution with $y$ even was already mentioned in the comments.

Edit': Thanks to Álvaro Lozano-Robledo for finding the reference, and Keith Conrad for informing me that the result is only quoted in the reference, not actually proven. Nonetheless, I am now sure that the result is true, and have an idea of the proof.  Álvaro Lozano-Robledo suggested a strategy using $2$-descent to show that the rank of this curve is $0$, and then using the Nagell-Lutz theorem to find the points of finite order. I will return to this post in some finite amount of time after doing some more reading and see if I can supply the proof.

Comment: Why?‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: Why are these the only rational points? That's a great question and I don't have a good answer. I just remember reading (somewhere) that this curve had rank $0$, and that these were the only rational points. Hopefully an expert sees this and can remark on it or give a reference.

Comment: My colleague Keith Conrad has some notes on this here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf, see Example 3.6.

Comment: needs another $y^2 = x^3 \large\bf{+1}$ upswag

Comment: The treatment of integral solutions to $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ in Example 3.6 of the reference Alvaro links to is  *incomplete*. It just turns that problem into the problem of solving $x^3 - 2y^3 = 1$ in integers.

Comment: Thank you @KCd, I searched the notes for the result, found it on the last page, and then assumed it was proven somewhere inside and vowed to read it later. I've edited the statement accordingly. I was able to find several references that solve $x^3-2y^3=1$ using Dirichlet's unit theorem and explicitly constructing certain fundamental units. Is this the "can of worms" referred to in the reference? Thanks again.

Comment: Dylan, yes it is. A different method that shows all the rational solutions are the ones you indicated is http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/descentbyeuler.pdf

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for positive integer solutions to $(2a)^2 = b^3+1$, or equivalently for $(2a-1)(2a+1)=b^3$.

Now we have two consecutive odd numbers on the LHS, so they are relatively prime (any common factor has to divide $2$, and they are odd).  Hence they both must be cubes.

Now it is easy to show that two consecutive cubes $x^3$ and $(x+1)^3$ are separated by $3x^2+3x+1$ which would be more than $2$ for positive $x$.

Answer (score 1):

[Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) states that  there are no two powers (with exponents $\geq2$) of natural numbers  at distance $1$ from each other, apart from $8$ and $9$. The conjecture has been proven by Preda Mihailescu in 2002.